# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, numpy

Given a text file with one DNA sequence on each line and joining these together I now want to split the string into 5 sequences (corresponding to each of the 5 rows).

This is the file source: http://www.programmingforbiologists.org/data/dna_sequences_1.txt

---

This is my code:

```
import numpy
dna_data=numpy.loadtxt("dna_sequences",dtype=str)
",".join(dna_data)
seq1,seq2,seq3,seq4,seq5=dna_data.split(",",4)
```

I am getting this error message:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: You need to store `",".join(dna_data)` in a variable that you split later on...but are you sure you need to join that if you're splitting it up in the next line?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @jadsq, there is not need for several variables here.

However, to address the error itself and as a reference for anyone facing the same error. The correct syntax for splitting a numpy array is:

```
seq1,seq2,seq3,seq4,seq5 = numpy.split(dna_data,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was said in the comments : `",".join(dna_data)` does not modify `dna_data` , it just returns a string that you have to store in an other variable. Like this :

```
s = ",".join(dna_data)
seq1,seq2,seq3,seq4,seq5=s.split(",",4)
```

**Going further :**

(Note as you seem to be new to numpy: In the following I'll assume `dna_data` has a shape `(5,)` if it is not the case, you can get back to that shape using [*very basic* slicing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) )

That being said, with that code, you are just turning your array into a list to then put in 5 different variables so going array->string->list->variables is **very excessive** when you could just go array->variables in one trivial line :  `seq1,seq2,seq3,seq4,seq5 = dna_data`.

And I would go even further : don't do it at all ! What is the point of having several variables when you just can just use `dna_data[n]` instead of any of your `seq*` variables ? The former is more convenient and allows to painlessly do things such as looping over all the sequence with for-loops. eg:

```
for seq in dna_data: 
    print(seq)
```